# how to add function that adds css style/class to text in simpleMDE?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, codemirror, simplemde

I cant do what is stated here: [How to add a custom Markdown function to SimpleMDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602961/how-to-add-a-custom-markdown-function-to-simplemde) 
which is:

```
function drawRedText(editor) {
var cm = editor.codemirror;
var output = '';
var selectedText = cm.getSelection();
var text = selectedText || 'placeholder';

output = '<p class="center">' + text + '</p>'; //.center is defined as {text-align: center;}
cm.replaceSelection(output);
}
```

As this will not work if I do it on '#h1' which is a heading.

Basically, I am trying to create a function that aligns the selection to the center.

Is there any way to add the styling to the selected/highlighted element?

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle with the code you have so far, to demonstrate what it is and isn't doing now?